# How do I identify the current page in a page collection?

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

I'm configuring a static site generator using Grunt's Assemble.io. I'm using the Pages Collection to build a navigation list like so:

```
{{#each pages }}
    <li><a href="{{{filename}} }">{{{title}} }</a></li>
{{/each }}
```

I would also like to apply `class="active"` to the navigation item for the current page, but I'm not sure how to approach this. My first thought was to try comparing the title of the current iteration of the collection to that of the page being rendered, but this has two problems:

1. The `if` helper in handlebars doesn't seem to have a way to compare two expressions. I could write a custom helper, but I would want to know this is the best way before I try it.
2. I don't know how to distinguish between the `title` of the current collection iteration and that of the current page. They would both be referred to as simply `title` as far as I can tell.

How can I determine when the pages collection loop is operating on the page which is the current page being rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isCurrentPage`](https://github.com/assemble/assemble/blob/master/test/fixtures/layouts/preprocess.hbs#L78)

```
{{#each pages }}
<li{{#if this.isCurrentPage}} class="active"{{/if}}>
    <a href="{{{filename}} }">{{{title}} }</a>
</li>
{{/each }}
```

Alternatively, you can use [isActive](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-isActive) helper.

Comment: I had implemented a solution using the `is` helper comparing `data.title` to the `title` of the page, but this is much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: fwiw, `this` isn't needed. In this kind of scenario, `this` is never necessary unless you're using a variable with the same name as a helper and you need to tell handlebars how to distinguish between the two.