# How to detect if page is current in {{#each pages}}?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, assemble

I'm only a couple days into learning [assemble](http://assemble.io) and I am attempting to create a table of contents using a partial.

---

toc.hbs

```
<ul >
{{#each  pages }}
    <li>
        <a  href ="{{assets }}/{{basename }}.html" >{{data.title }}</a >
    </li >
{{/each  }}
</ul >
```

---

layout.hbs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        {{> toc}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        {{> body}}
    </div>
</div>
```

---

This works fine except I'd like to set class="active" on the current page.

**Q:** Is there a way to easily do this using the built-in functionality of assemble & handlebars? Do I need to use a helper like [ifCond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853396/logical-operator-in-a-handlebars-js-if-conditional)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I identify the current page in a page collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630251/how-do-i-identify-the-current-page-in-a-page-collection)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `{{#is}}` and `{{/is}}` block to conditionally add the style.

```
<li {{#is title "Features"}}class="active"{{/is}}>
  <a href="features.html">Features</a>
</li>
```

You could do the comparison on `basename` or other fields if you don't think title is stable enough.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing around I finally discovered the `{{debug}}` helper which prints out the entire context to the console. From this I discovered that there's an undocumented property `isCurrentPage`, which returns `true` when the page is the current one being processed.

**Result:**

```
<ul >
{{#each  pages }}
    <li {{#if isCurrentPage}}class="active"{{/if}}>
        <a href ="{{assets }}/{{basename }}.html" >{{data.title }}</a >
    </li >
{{/each  }}
</ul >
```

Comment: After searching for isCurrentPage, I discovered this question is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630251/how-do-i-identify-the-current-page-in-a-page-collection